# How to create multiple azure RDS tenant using ARM template or terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-resource-manager, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm

I find a way to create one RDS-tenant using terraform :

```
resource "null_resource" "createTenant" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
   command = <<EOT
    Add-RdsAccount -DeploymentUrl https://rdbroker.wvd.microsoft.com
    New-RdsTenant -Name ${var.tenant_name} -AadTenantId ${var.aad_tenant_id} -AzureSubscriptionId  ${var.subscription_id}
    New-RdsRoleAssignment -RoleDefinitionName "RDS Owner" -ApplicationId ${azuread_application.wvd_app.application_id} -TenantName ${var.tenant_name}
    New-RdsHostPool -TenantName ${var.tenant_name} -Name ${var.host_pool_name}
  EOT
interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }
}
```

but in this case "terraform state" is does'not track the resources changes
So it is not reliable way to implement the tenant resource creation and there is no way to implement or create multiple tenant using this ...

Do we any ARM template reference  or resource ????

Comment: hey swetank, does the below answer help?

Comment: Nope!!!   You could also raise an issue to the azurerm provider to request a new resource to be created: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues

Answer (score 0):

As there isn't a resource for this in the terraform `azurerm` provider it can't be managed easily within that traditional lifecycle you are referring to.

Microsoft has a repository dedicated to **Remote Desktop Service Templates** which is located: https://github.com/Azure/RDS-Templates

You could wrap this in PowerShell to build multiple instances of this in a repeatable way.

Or you could look at contributing the `azurerm` provider. If you are interested in doing that there is great documentation: https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/community/contributing.html

You could also raise an issue to the `azurerm` provider to request a new resource to be created: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @Lachie White for a h.. well It means we don't have any custom solution for RDS-tenant for now as it to lack resources to terraform azurerm provider, so we have to wait till they add this as a new resources..so NO SOLUTION TILL NOW